# Error of Taylor Series e^x for negative x

Tags: c, taylor-series

I was calculating e^x using Taylor Series and noticed that when we calculate it for negative x absolute error is large.Is it because we don't have enough precision to calculate it?

(I know that to prevent it we can use e^(-x)=1/e^x)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double Exp(double x);

int main(void)
{
    double x;
    printf("x="); 
    scanf("%le", &x);

    printf("%le", Exp(x)); 
    return 0;
}

double Exp(double x)
{
    double h, eps = 1.e-16, Sum = 1.0; 
    int i = 2;

    h = x; 

    do
    {
        Sum += h; 
        h *= x / i;
        i++;
    } while (fabs(h) > eps);

    return Sum ; 
}
```

For example:
x=-40 the value is 4.24835e-18 but programm gives me 3.116952e-01.The absolute error is ~0.311

x=-50 the value is 1.92875e-22 programm gives me 2.041833e+03.The absolute error is ~2041.833

Comment: Help your readers see what you see. How have you noticed it using the code you shared?

Comment: Show a value of `x` that demonstrates the situation, show the result you obtain, and state what absolute error you observe.

Comment: Add a print for the value of `h` at each iteration. It's juggling some large rather positive and negative numbers in the hope of getting to a small result. [Subtraction is dangerous.](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/propagation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by rounding errors at the middle phase of the algorithm.
The `h` is growing quickly as `40/2 * 40/3 * 40 / 4 * ...` and oscillating in sign. The values for `i`, `h` and `Sum` for `x=-40` for consecutive iterations can be found below (some data points omitted for brevity):

```
x=-40
i=2 h=800 Sum=-39
i=3 h=-10666.7 Sum=761
i=4 h=106667 Sum=-9905.67
i=5 h=-853333 Sum=96761
i=6 h=5.68889e+06 Sum=-756572
...
i=37 h=-1.37241e+16 Sum=6.63949e+15
i=38 h=1.44464e+16 Sum=-7.08457e+15
i=39 h=-1.48168e+16 Sum=7.36181e+15
i=40 h=1.48168e+16 Sum=-7.45499e+15
i=41 h=-1.44554e+16 Sum=7.36181e+15
i=42 h=1.37671e+16 Sum=-7.09361e+15
i=43 h=-1.28066e+16 Sum=6.67346e+15
i=44 h=1.16423e+16 Sum=-6.13311e+15
i=45 h=-1.03487e+16 Sum=5.50923e+15
i=46 h=8.99891e+15 Sum=-4.83952e+15
...
i=97 h=-2610.22 Sum=1852.36
i=98 h=1065.4 Sum=-757.861
i=99 h=-430.463 Sum=307.534
...
i=138 h=1.75514e-16 Sum=0.311695
i=139 h=-5.05076e-17 Sum=0.311695
3.116952e-01
```

The peak magnitude of sum is `7e15`. This is where the precision is lost. Type `double` can be represented with about `1e-16` accuracy. This gives expected absolute error of about `0.1 - 1`.
As the expected sum (value of `exp(-40)` is close to zero the final absolute error is close to the maximal absolute error of the partial sums.

For `x=-50` the peak value of sum is `1.5e20` what gives the absolute error due to finite representation of `double` at about `1e3 - 1e4` what is close to observed one.

Not much can be fixed without significant changes to algorithm to avoid forming those partial sums. Alternatively, compute `exp(-x)` as `1/exp(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

For negative x, adding the alternating +/- terms creates a computational problems even in the first sum of `1.0 + x` as the final sum error can be expected to be as bad as the least significant bit of 1.0 or about 1 part in 10<sup>16</sup>.  This implies `x_min` as in `Exp(x_min) == 1.0e-16` is the minimum useful computational value (e.g. `x` about -36)

A simple solution is to form a good `Exp(positive_x)` and for negative values ...

```
double Exp(double x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    return 1.0 / Exp(-x);
  }
  ...
```

A good (and simple) `Exp(positive_x)` computes terms until a `term + 1.0` is still 1.0 as additional small terms do not change the sum significantly.  Works well for **all** `x` (very small error) except could use improvements when the result should be a sub-normal.

```
double my_exp(double x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    return 1.0 / my_exp(-x);
  }
  double sum = 1.0;
  unsigned n = 1;
  double term = 1.0;
  do {
    term *= x / n++;
    sum += term;
    if (!isfinite(term)) {
      return term;
    }
  } while (1.0 != term + 1.0);
  return sum;
}
```